# How do I disable monster level scaling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to configure Skyrim to be like [Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul](http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=OblivionMods.Detail&id=3953), where it makes monster difficulty more realistic?

That Oblivion mod did so mainly by removing monster level scaling with player level. Monsters were given a static difficulty based on their type and some other factors. For example, all wolves were easier than all trolls. I enjoyed the challenge of being aware of the type of enemies I was facing and needing to test whether they were too strong. In the built-in system, it's generally possible to kill almost anything starting at early levels, and there is no sense of excitement at being able to go somewhere that had previously been restricted.

Comment: OOO didn't quite completely remove scaling, it just tweaked the min/max level values on a bunch of things, and allowed higher level monsters to spawn despite the player being at low levels.  It was an awesome mod, I still remember the first time I ran into a frost titan just outside of Bruma as a level 2 character.  Fortunately the guards (and half the town) did just enough damage to weaken it before they all died so I could kill it.

Comment: Skyrim has tiered monsters (and dungeons) - they'll scale to a certain extent, [but have a minimum and maximum level](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dungeons). The first time I walked into the Guldun Rock giants' camp, I learned to stay the hell away from giants, until much later.

Comment: I've reworded the question to not ask specifically for a mod recommendation, and to ask for any solution instead. Voting to reopen as per the meta posts: […looking for mods for specific purposes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11578/4797) "*Give us the actual problem… and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves a mod, so be it*", and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797) "*This is not a shopping recommendation (a request for subjective… advice). The problem can be clearly stated and objectively evaluated in most cases.*"

Answer (score 8):

> **[Skyrim Scaling Stopper](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9857/)** and **[Real Unleveled Skyrim](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/73272/)** both do away with scaling of actors (monsters, people etc) but in different ways.
>
> SSS makes almost everything about the same level, with some very weak (especially near Whiterun) and very rare highly powerful spawns. The numbers of like this - 20% of spawns are level 1-14, 77% are level 15-20, 3% are level 21-50. So if you're level 1 you're going to get your arse handed to you most of the time; if you're level 50 you're going to breeze past most enemies.
>
> RUS makes levelled spawns a lot more evenly spread out - some specific areas are fine at low levels; others shouldn't even be approached until much later in the game.
>
> As for items, I think both those mods affect loot/enemy gear too. SSS spawns good stuff very rarely, and randomly; RUS has the best stuff in the most difficult places.
>
> **[Morrowloot](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/44212/)*** is something that removes the scaling of items only, and well worth using (load it after one of the above mods). It makes items pretty much static & logical, so you'll only find dwemer items in dwemer ruins; orcish armour is only ever use by orcs; and so on.

<sup>Source: [Reddit /r/skyrimmods comment by user Iogic in the post, "*Are there any MODS that remove or reduce scaling?*"](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/wlf2w/are_there_any_mods_that_remove_or_reduce_scaling/)</sup>
<sup>* There is a modified version of Morrowloot here: [Morrowloot - N'wah Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19416/).</sup>

Comment: Are these mods balanced? I really enjoy Enderal and would love to play Skyrim with a difficulty similar to Skyrim

Answer (score 3):

The overhaul mod Requiem as well as the Skyrim Redone module 'Encounter zones' do the exact thing you are looking for.